# Playfamework searching in database

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

hello I got small problem I have project made in playframework and I must find all surnames in database , I have made it by using function

```
List<Classname> surnames = classname.find.all()
```

but then when I request http I get everything user name, surname, mail, id.

I was thinking about make this using

```
List<Account> users = Account.find.where().like("surname","surname").findList();
```

But when I get request with this function from http i get only []

Could somebody help me? I will be very thankful

I have done as you said but this on get request gives me more than only surnames I have made it now like

```
    List<Account> surnam = Account.find.where().orderBy("surname asc").findList();
    Vector<String> surnames = new Vector<>();
                for(Account a: surnam)
                {
                   surnames.add(a.getSurname());
                }
```

And now this shows me only sorted surnames but is here way to do it much prettier, I mean without using for each loop?

Comment: Is this Java? Scala? Ebean? JPA? Slick? Not everyone is using the same tools you are within Play, so you should provide as much information as possible. You're more likely to find help that way.

Comment: @user... you should tag your question with better precision in the future, also make usage of built-in code formatter on the StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Account> accounts = Account.find.select("surname").findList();
```

will create a query (pseudo code)

```
SELECT id, surname FROM account
```

Note that Ebean ALWAYS adds the `id` field to the query for mapping purposes

If you want to search by some field i.e. to find all John Does use:

```
List<Account> accounts = Account.find.select("surname").where().like("surname", "%Doe%").findList();
```

which will create query:

```
SELECT id, surname FROM account WHERE surname LIKE '%Doe%'
```